# How to make a numericupdown control for asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

does anybody know how to make a numericupdown control for asp. There's one for making winforms, but I don't know if theres one for making webforms. Is there an addon or something that I can use?

Comment: @Adyt: FYI, there's a minimum character limit of (I think) 10 characters for answers and comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use AJAX.NET, there is a [numericupdown control](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx).

Check http://ajax.asp.net/